# jQuery Rails - .post Data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here is the code in my application.js file:

```
  this.change(function() {
    $.post("dvbd", {id: this.val()}, null, "script");
  });
```

Here is what is in dvbd.js.erb:

```
$("#dave").html(:id);
```

What I'm trying to do is when `this` changes, the dave div has the value of `this` as its html. So I guess my question is how would I use the data sent using .post in my js.erb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#dave").html("<%= params[:id] %>");
```